# Electron-packager returning "Response code 404 (Not Found)" when trying to compile electron project to .exe using CMD on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron, electron-packager

I am a beginner developer, just familiarising myself with electron and node.js. I am trying to convert my electron project into a .exe file using the electron-packager package, but every time I attempt it returns this error:

```
Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v0.35.6/SHASUMS256.txt
```

I have tried the URL, and it returns an error 404, apparently, anything from "releases" down doesn't exist. I am using Windows 10 if that helps.

Here is my main.js file:

```
    var app = require('app');  // Module to control application life.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');  // Module to create native browser window.

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 600});

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL("path to index.html");

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

(the "path to index.html" is substituted for the real path in the actual script)

This is the package.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "overboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "pretty-bytes": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.35.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "init": "npm install",
    "start": "electron main.js"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform != "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on("ready", function() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 600 });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    // Not sure where your index.html is placed but if you are using Electron-quick-starter then this will be right.
    // Plus mainWindow.loadURL("https://github.com") not for loading the local file but for loading the url at your browser.

    mainWindow.loadFile("./index.html"); 


    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on("closed", function() {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

`electron-built` has been renamed to `electron` long time ago.
So you should update your `package.json`

```
 {
  "name": "overboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "pretty-bytes": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest",
    "electron-forge": "latest",
    "electron-packager": "latest",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "init": "npm install",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Pls remove your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
And try `npm install` and `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the exact same error differently.

Got the error when trying out a react-native-chat-tutorial app by GetStream https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-chat-tutorial

```
cd react-native-chat-tutorial

yarn

[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
error <my-app-path>/react-native-chat-tutorial/node_modules/electron: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: <my-app-path>/react-native-chat-tutorial/node_modules/electron
Output:
HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.3/electron-v9.4.3-darwin-arm64.zip
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous>
```

Found that in my case the root cause was `react-devtools` trying to get TODO which did not work with Apple Silicon (M1) chip.

Got some dirty workaround directions from this helpful comment on GitHub https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20454#issuecomment-888992424

Eventually what worked for me was changing the version of `react-devtools` in `package.json`

```
FROM
"react-devtools": "^4.10.1",
TO
"react-devtools": "4.22.1",
```

because that was the latest version at the time https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools#local-development